How to obtain the radius of convergence of a Taylor expansion for $e^{−1/x^2}$ at point $x=a$?
While poking around here and there about analytic functions, I came across the function
$$ f(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} , x \neq 0 $$
(extended to $f(0)=0$ by continuity)
which seems to raise a lot of questions about its analyticity: I saw that there are dozens of posts about it on StackExchange Mathematics...
So, I just wanted to see what's going on with this function?
I understood that this function is infinitely differentiable at any point with the $n^{th}$ derivative:
$$ f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{P_n(x)}{x^{3n}} e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} $$
where $P_n(x)$ is a polynomial starting with $P_0(x)=1$ and given recursively by $P_{n+1}(x)=x^3 P_n^{'}(x) + (2-3nx) P_n(x)$.
So that we can derive:
$$ P_1(x)=2,\, P_2(x)=-6x^2+4,\, P_3(x)=24x^4-36x^2+8,\, etc. $$
Following that, we can construct a Taylor expansion in any point $x=a$:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (x-a)^n=…$$
$$ e^{-\frac{1}{a^2}} \left( 1 + \frac{2}{a^3} (x-a) + \frac{-6a^2+4}{2a^6} (x-a)^2 + \frac{24a^4-36a^2+8}{6a^9} (x-a)^3 + … \right) $$
Plot below shows a Taylor expansion at order $3$ for point $a=1$:

The question for which I can't find an answer is how to calculate the radius of convergence of the power series represented by the Taylor expansion above at the point $x=a$?
As the coefficient of the power series is :
$$ a_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} = \frac{P_n(a)}{n! a^{3n}} e^{\frac{-1}{a^2}} $$
and since $P_n$ is given by recurrence, I don't see how to apply the Cauchy-Hadamard formula to calculate the radius?
Is there another method to do so?

mmmh, could you explain the logic? I dont know the link between radius and singularity. (missing something maybe obvious, I guess...)

So, I must have gone over the theory too quickly, because it doesn't mean anything to me anymore... how could I find out more?

You usually encounter this result in complex analysis

I don't deny this, but the function I used in the post is a real function...

As already pointed out in the comments there is a strong link to holomorphic (i.e. complex-analytic) functions:

A function $f\colon I\to \mathbb R$ defined on some open interval $I\subseteq \mathbb R$ is real-analytic if and only if there exists a domain $D\subseteq \mathbb C$ that contains $I$ and a holomorphic function $\tilde f\colon D\to \mathbb C$ such that $\tilde f|_I=f$.

If $f\colon D\to \mathbb C$ is holomorphic (where $D$ is some domain in $\mathbb C$) and $a\in D$ is some point in $D$, then the Taylor series of $f$ centered at $a$ converges to $f$ on every open disk $B_r(a)$ with $0<r<\operatorname{dist}(a,\partial D)$, where
$$
\operatorname{dist}(a,\partial D)=\inf\lbrace |z-a|: z\in \partial D\rbrace\in [0,\infty]
$$
is the distance of $a$ to the (possibly empty) boundary of $D$. That's where "radius of convergence = distance to nearest singularity / branch point" comes from.
$x\mapsto \exp(-\tfrac 1{x^2})$ can be extended to $\mathbb C^\times=\mathbb C\setminus\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ and is holomorphic on this domain. Therefore the radius of convergence of the Taylor series in question is
$$
\operatorname{dist}(a,\partial \mathbb C^\times)=\operatorname{dist}(a,\lbrace 0\rbrace)=|a-0|=|a|.
$$

Thanks Nico. This is a very good explanation of some points I have never encountered!
I deduce from your answer that the Taylor series of $f:x-> exp(-1/x^2)$ at some point $a$ converges in any open disk $B_r(a)$ where $0<r<|a|$. Is this the right deduction to draw? But on the other hand, for an $x_0$ in that $B_r(a)$, it does not necessarily converge to $exp(-1/x_0^2)$... Still right?

@Andrew Since this function is analytic on the respective domain the Taylor series does converge to $\exp(-1/x^2)$ on every such disk.

I am very glad that you answered me like that, because that is what I thought: for me, we can say that this function is analytic on $\mathbb R\setminus\lbrace 0 \rbrace$. My confusion comes from the fact that in French, analytic does not seem to have quite the same meaning as in English.

Thus, I found mentions that the function in question is not analytic:
"Par exemple $x -> e^{-1/x^2}$ prolongée par $0$ to $0$ is $C^{\infty}$ mais non analytique."
(For example $x -> e^{-1/x^2}$ extended by $0$ to $0$ is $C^{\infty}$ but not analytic).  In : https://perso.eleves.ens-rennes.fr/~afalq494/docs_maths/maths_agreg/Memoire_sur_la_lecon_243.pdf (see 4.15, page 7)
I think people mean "non-analytic in $0$"...

If you continuously extend the function to all of $\mathbb R$, this extension is not analytic (because it is not analytic at $0$). If we only look at $x\mapsto \exp(-1/x^2)$ on $\mathbb R\setminus\lbrace 0\rbrace$, however, the function is analytic.
